# Airflow / Composer - Info Logs being sent to stderr ? - Causes logging to show as errors

Tags: logging, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I have composer environments, which seem to be sending their logs to an error location - resulting in stackdriver showing 10's of thousands of entries as errors. .when i look at the errors, they seem to be standard log entries, no failures errors etc.

Where can i change the logging location or check the logging location for composer environments ?

Answer (score 1):

[Airflow logs](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/logs) are saved in the bucket that was created along with your Cloud Composer environment. The logs are separated per DAG and per execution, so let's say you ran your DAG twice, you will have 2 log files. These logs contains the errors in your DAG (if you have errors). The folder structure in your bucket will look like this:

```
gs://your-cloud-composer-bucket/logs/DAG1/*
gs://your-cloud-composer-bucket/logs/DAG2/*
gs://your-cloud-composer-bucket/logs/DAG3/*
....
```

The bucket location of the Airflow logs cannot be changed as this is automatically generated when creating a Composer environment.

The logs saved in the bucket are only limited to Airflow logs. The [audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/audit-logging) like environment creation, deletion and update are only found in the stackdriver logging. It is up to you if you want to create a sink to store the audit logs.